# Qt Network Broadcasting Question: To get sender IP

Tags: qt, networking, udp, broadcast

There is a simple example about network broadcasting in QtSDK. It is easy to send and receive broadcast information. And in the receiver side, I want to know whose broadcast packet I just received. I try QUdpSocket.peerName() in  readyRead signal callback function,but I get empty string. Any clue?

Comment: have youu found any solution

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the sender's IP address when reading the packet with [QUdpSocket::readDatagram()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qudpsocket.html#readDatagram). You need to pass to readDatagram() a pointer to a QHostAddress in which to store the address:

```
QHostAddress senderAddress;
yourSocket->readDatagram(&data, size, &senderAddress);
// senderAddress now represents the sender address
```

You can get the address as a QString or integer from senderAddress if you need to, see the documentation for [QHostAddress](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qhostaddress.html).

If you want a host name, you can use [QHostInfo](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qhostinfo.html) to do a reverse lookup (but you are not guaranteed to get a name).

Comment: After socket->readDatagram, QString ip = socket->peerAddress().toString(); I get empty string.

Comment: @cantinred Edited. You need to pass to readDatagram() a pointer to a QHostAddress in which to store the address.

Comment: @Leiaz It doesn't work. The address you get (in senderAddress) is 0.0.0.0 when receiving a broadcast packet. I thought it would work too, but either Qt is doing something stupid or Linux's underlying socket implementation gives you an empty source address for received broadcast packets.

Comment: @Leiaz actually, I take that back... turns out in my scenario, the sender was providing a zero source address (it was a PXE BIOS that hadn't gotten an address yet!). So what I should have said was, you won't *necessarily* get a source address, but in a typical scenario, you will.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Returns the name of the peer as specified by connectToHost(), or an empty QString if connectToHost() has not been called.

So, if you've called `connectToHost()` you should get a result.  You might also try [peerAddress()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qabstractsocket.html#peerAddress). Unless you always connect via a name, I wouldn't expect that you'll always be able to do a reverse lookup and get a name.